# Is a function call returning a pointer to an object a prvalue?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, value-categories

Let's imagine this function:

```
C* get(C* c, int offset) {
    return c + offset;
}
```

I would like to know if a call to this function is evaluated as a prvalue:

```
C array_c[3];
C* c2 = get(array_c, 2);
```

Is `get(array_c, 2)` a prvalue?

According to [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) page on cppreference:

> - a **glvalue** (“generalized” lvalue) is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object, bit-field, or function;
> - a **prvalue** (“pure” rvalue) is an expression whose evaluation either :
>
>   - computes a value that is not associated with an object
>   - creates a temporary object and denotes it
> - an **xvalue** (an “eXpiring” value) is a glvalue that denotes an object or bit-field whose resources can be reused;
> - an **lvalue** (so-called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression) is a glvalue that is not an xvalue;

In our example, the expression `get(array_c, 2)` points to an already exising object that doesn't expire after the call. So we can say it is an lvalue. Moreover, we can write `*get(array_c, 2) = C{};` to assign a value to the expression.

However, there are two points that make me think it is not an lvalue. First of all, in the same page of cppreference:

> The following expressions are prvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is non-reference

In our example, the `get` function returns a non-reference so, according to this definition, the call should be evaluated as an prvalue.

Also, I'm wondering if `get(array_c, 2)` is indeed a temporary that makes it a prvalue and `*get(array_c, 2)` is an lvalue because we can assign a value to it.

What do you think? Is the function call evaluated as an lvalue, a prvalue (or something else)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`get(array_c, 2)` and `*get(array_c, 2)` are two different expressions, and have different value categories.

`get` returns pointer by value itself, then `get(array_c, 2)` is considered as an rvalue (prvalue) expression. You can't perform assignment on it like `get(array_c, 2) = nullptr;` or get address from it like `&get(array_c, 2)`, it's just same as if `get` returns other types like `int`.

On the other hand, `*get(array_c, 2)` is an [lvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue). As you said you can perform assignment on it, which is valid or not, the returned pointer is valid or not doesn't matter.

> `*p`, the built-in [indirection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_indirection_operator) expression;

---

PS: Assignment might be performed on rvalues of class type; it's not an absolute condition for determining lvalue expressions or not.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use assignment as an example, as it can be done on rvalues of class types.

Comment: @jrok You're right. I keep it because OP's mentioning it (so it might help OP to understand) and it's true for built-in types as in OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

`get(array_c, 2)` and `*get(array_c, 2)` are not the same expression; they don't both have to be in the same value category.

`get(array_c, 2)` is a prvalue.

> The following expressions are *prvalue expressions*:
>
> ...
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is non-reference...

`*get(array_c, 2)` is an lvalue.

> The following expressions are *lvalue expressions*:
>
> ...
>
> - `*p`, the built-in indirection expression;

([Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category))